# Efficient SQL query where column equals another column

Tags: mysql, sql

Searching for an *efficient* (i.e. uses indexes) MySQL query for selecting rows where in value of one column in a given row equals the value in another column in the same row, i.e.:

```
SELECT row_id FROM mytable WHERE row_id=some_id
```

`row_id` is the PRIMARY index.  `some_id` has its own separate non-unique index.  Is there a way to do this without requiring a whole table scan?

[Clarification/Edit]

`row_id` and `some_id` are both of the same type, `unsigned int`.  Each is a column, and each has an index, albeit `row_id` is unique and `some_id` may not be.

Comment: if there an index on row_id then it will use the row_id if some_id is the same type.

Comment: what does it do currently, can you post the `explain extended` output?

Comment: Theoretically it should be able to make use of the two indexes to implement this, but I wouldn't be surprised if MySQL doesn't have that optimization.

Comment: It also might depend on the cardinality of the two indexes. If `some_id` has low cardinality, a full scan might be done instead.

Answer (score 0):

`row_id` and `some_id` are both columns, right? I don't think there's a way to guarantee a full table scan won't be required, even with an index (for instance, consider both columns being pairwise unique). In such a case, AFAIK your index will improve performance, (binary search lookup will mean individual comparison will be faster) but won't circumvent a full-table scan.